# Performant texture region copies in Metal

Tags: quartz-graphics, nsimage, metal

I've got my eye upon Metal as an option for performing very performant pixel copies at 60fps.

Let me phrase my question in terms of an existing technology...

I have the attached 1920x1080 `NSImage` and I want to blit this into an `NSView` in a "mosaic"-type fashion. Assume this image is a frame of video, so it would more likely be an RGBA32-formatted `CVPixelBuffer`). Each of these 9 coloured regions could end up in random locations on the screen.

[image: A mosaic of tiles]

I could use the [`drawInRect`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/1520067-drawinrect) function from the `NSImage` API to perform 9 such copy calls from the source of my image to the target `NSView`. The data model in this case would involve 9 source-target CGRect pairs, and then 9 such calls to perform the copies.

I suspect this is a very slow approach as compared to what could happen in Metal.  It could possibly be accelerated if the `NSView` were Metal-backed.

**Can someone enlighten me as to what a very performant Metal version of this would be?**

The intent would be to upload the entire texture as-is, once to the GPU and then issue a set of GPU-based calls to (eventually) blit the texture's regions onto screen.  Assume that the source pixel format is RGBA32.  The intent obviously is for only one CPU->GPU pixel data transfer (no round trips!).

Would such an approach first involve the use of the [copyFromBuffer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlblitcommandencoder/1400752-copyfrombuffer?language=objc) to get the image on the GPU, then a set of 9 calls to [copyFromTexture](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlblitcommandencoder/1400754-copyfromtexture?language=objc) to finalize the texture for presentation?  Then mapping that texture onto a quad on-screen.  Just surmising.  What would this look like?

(The fact that Metal2 now has some one-time argument buffers is appealing to me and may just be a lower-level implementation of the two aforementioned functions from the `MTLBlitCommandEncoder`.  If this is a more performant lower-level implementation, what would that look like instead?)

Any guidance on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that just about any approach that's not overly complicated would be plenty performant. There are very few vertices and only one texture involved.

You could create the initial texture using [`MTKTextureLoader`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalkit/mtktextureloader) and its methods to create a texture from a `CGImage` or even from the original image data source (URL or image asset). Or, since you mentioned Core Video, you can get Metal textures directly from that.

If you want to draw different sectors of that texture to different sectors of the view, I'd draw 9 quads (in a single draw call) and just use the appropriate texture coordinates for each one. No need to copy chunks of the texture from place to place.

Comment: Yeah, rasterization is going to be faster and more flexible than blitting or copying here.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, Ken and Warren. My understanding is that CVPixelBuffers from an AVPlayer (or AVAssetReader) are loaded on the GPU anyways for pixel format conversion.

The 9 quads I mention could extended be more -- and not be of uniform size (but all still rectangular). I'd be interested in being able to render a (x,y,w,h) region from one master texture (video frame) onto a target quad of the same size in a disparate (x,y) position. There'd be "list" of ≈50 of these mappings. Barring that, I could resort to a pixel shader in Metal!

Any further hints would be appreciated!

Comment: If it's a help, think of my scenario has an image "mapped" onto a set of square and rectangular wooden play blocks that collectively form a full 1920x1080 image.  Then I want to have the ability to randomly scramble the blocks, with the affixed image on each going along for the ride.

Comment: The advice remains the same. Even with 50 quads, that's still trivial for the GPU. You would just provide vertices with texcoords such that, when the fragment shader samples the texture using the texcoords it receives, it gets texels from the desired portion of the texture.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement, Ken.  I did some OpenGL programming years ago but nothing on Metal.  I will look into this.  I was being pushed in the direction of using a pixel shader but that seemed inappropriate for the task at hand.

Comment: Well, all drawing in Metal will involve a pixel shader, but the one required here is really simple. You would write it to receive `stage_in` input that carries the texcoords. It would also receive a reference to the texture with your image. It would probably return a `float4` as the color for the fragment. It would simply return the result of sampling the texture at the texcoords.